# crystal reports : left() function outputs symbols?

Tags: crystal-reports

When I run the following:

```
left({_v_kap.cpudesc}, (instr({_v_kap.cpudesc},",") ))
```

the function outputs :  ¤¤Y¤  and other variations

however if I just run

```
   left({_v_kap.cpudesc}, 48)
```

it returns the string correctly up to character 48 
and if I just run

```
instr({_v_kap.cpudesc},",")
```

it returns 48

If I combine them, shouldn't this work?
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  If the instr() function doesn't find the item, the entire function bombs.

I checked the statement to see if its greater than zero. check if it runs, do it, otherwise don't check for the comma

pos := instr({_v_kap.cpudesc},",")

if pos > 0 then 
left({_v_kap.cpudesc}, (instr({_v_kap.cpudesc},",") ))
else 
{_v_kap.cpudesc}

this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Phill,

In the code you provided one ")" is missing.

I believe it should be

```
left({_v_kap.cpudesc}, (instr({_v_kap.cpudesc},",") ) )
```

Thnks

Comment: I added that in and it didn't seem to make a difference.  thanks for the response